# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application supported, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook shown as an Syste.Com Object

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-charts

I got a problem with the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` Service. The Application-Class is shown as such one, the Workbook-Class is shown as a System.Com-Object:

[image: Some information to my problem]

Im using `Ex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

On on hand, the call of `ExWB.Worksheets.Count` was successfully performed.
On the other, the watcher doesn't show it.

The exception is not really very spezific.

What am I doning wrong by calling `Ex.Chart ExChr = (Ex.Chart)ExWB.Charts.Add(ExWB.Worksheets.Count);` making the exception occure.

Thank you very much,
Jan

Comment: Are you using `Add(ExWB.Worksheets.Count)` or `Add(ExWB.Worksheets.Count) + 1` as in the screenshot? What happens if you remove the 1?

Comment: My comment should say `.Count + 1)`

Comment: I tried `.Count + 1`, `.Count` and `1` - and I tried nothing, because this argument is optional. Now, the call of `.Worksheets.Count` throws an exception.

Comment: I'm quite sure, there is an problem with the Interop.

Comment: Ok, found my problem. The workbook was corrupt - I created it by datetransfer via OleDb. Creating the Workbook first via Office.Interop, closing it, filling by OleDb makes my code working.